# Why stop the loop after remove an element?

Tags: python, loops

I've the following code snippet. Why do the loop not remove all points from list `points`, I'm very confused about that. I mean, all points are in the triangle.

```
print "check whether",points,"are in triangle"
print "p=",points[0]," is in triangle=",isPointInTri(a,b,c,points[0])
print "p=",points[1]," is in triangle=",isPointInTri(a,b,c,points[1])

for p in points:
    if isPointInTri(a,b,c,p):
        points.remove(p)
    print "now, the following points are available", points
print points
```

This is the output:

```
check whether [(2, 1), (4, 1)] are in triangle
p= (2, 1)  is in triangle= True
p= (4, 1)  is in triangle= True
now, the following points are available [(4, 1)]
[(4, 1)]
```

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: You are removing elements from a list you are iterating over.

Comment: This is not a complete example. What are `a`, `b`, and `c`? How is `isPointInTri` defined?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python got good answers too.

Comment: you are right but its not important to know `a`,`b`,`c` or the `isPointInTri`. The Problem is the loop. Maybe, I should not remove an item during the iteration on the same list.

Comment: @Sam But *is* important to have a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)...

Comment: @glglgl okey, sorry :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying the list that you are iterating over. You should never do this. The reason is that the `for` loop uses something called an *iterator*, which basically points to a *current* element in the list, and in each iteration moves to the next one. When the list is being modified the iterator doesn't know about it. When you remove an element, the iterator still points to "the same place in memory" even though the list is shorter now. So it is after the end of the collection and "thinks" it has already passed over all elements.

Try this instead:

```
points = [p for p in points if not isPointInTri(a,b,c,p)]
```

There is also a built-in [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function for this:

```
 points = filter(lambda p: not isPointInTri(a,b,c,p), points)
```

Also, the simplest fix to use your code literally is to copy the initial list:

```
for p in points[:]:
    if isPointInTri(a,b,c,p):
        points.remove(p)
    print "now, the following points are available", points
print points
```

The slicing operator used like this (`[:]`) will make a copy of `points`.